# How to combine these two queries into one? (multiple joins against the same table)

Tags: mysql

Given two tables, one for workers and one for tasks completed by workers,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `workers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `workers` (`id`) VALUES
(1);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tasks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `worker_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `tasks` (`id`, `worker_id`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 1),
(3, 1, 2),
(4, 1, 2),
(5, 1, 2);
```

I'm trying to get the number of tasks each worker has with each status code.

I can say either

```
SELECT w.*
,COUNT(t1.worker_id) as status_1_count
FROM workers w
LEFT JOIN tasks t1 ON w.id = t1.worker_id AND t1.status = 1 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY 
t1.worker_id
ORDER BY w.id
```

or

```
SELECT w.*
,COUNT(t2.worker_id) as status_2_count
FROM workers w
LEFT JOIN tasks t2 ON w.id = t2.worker_id AND t2.status = 2
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY 
t2.worker_id
ORDER BY w.id
```

and get the number of tasks with a single given status code, but when I try to get the counts for multiple task statuses in a single query, it doesn't work!

```
SELECT w.*
,COUNT(t1.worker_id) as status_1_count
,COUNT(t2.worker_id) as status_2_count
FROM workers w
LEFT JOIN tasks t1 ON w.id = t1.worker_id AND t1.status = 1 
LEFT JOIN tasks t2 ON w.id = t2.worker_id AND t2.status = 2
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY t1.worker_id
,t2.worker_id
ORDER BY w.id
```

The tasks table is cross-joining against itself when I would rather it wouldn't!

Is there any way to combine these two queries into one such that we can retrieve the counts for multiple task statuses in a single query?

Thanks!

Comment: You want (1) a list of workers, statuses, and a count of the number of tasks for each worker and status, and also (2) a list of status codes plus the count of the number of tasks with that status code (but not specifically for a given worker). That's a problem; you have 2 and 3 columns to select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT w.*,
  SUM(t1.status = 1) AS status_1_count,
  SUM(t1.status = 2) AS status_2_count
FROM workers w
  LEFT JOIN tasks t1 ON w.id = t1.worker_id AND t1.status IN (1, 2) 
GROUP BY w.id
ORDER BY w.id;
```

Comment: I didn't know you could conditionalize aggregations statements--that's handy, and does what I need with even fewer joins than I was hoping for; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to get the number of tasks each worker has with each status code.

```
SELECT worker_id, status, COUNT(*)
    FROM tasks
    GROUP BY worker_id, status;
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an instance of MySQL here, but I tested this on a t-sql box and it worked.

```
select distinct(worker_id), 
       (select count(*) from tasks where status = 1) as Status1, 
       (select count(*) from tasks where status = 2) as Status2 
   from tasks;
```